# Django-модель User создает поле user_ptr_id

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь обновить **Django** c 2 на 3.2.

У меня своя модель User-а:

```
class Agent(User):

    objects = AgentManager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        editable=False,
        related_name='agent',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        parent_link=True,
    )
```

**Django**-модель User-а делает его *swappable*:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
    model.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

Запускаю тесты с пустой базой и получаю ошибку:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_ptr_id" of relation "staff_agent" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

На этапе миграций создается поле `user_ptr_id`, которое не создавалось на **Django** 2, и далее оно не заполняется, потому и выдает ошибку.

Вопрос состоит в следующем: как отключить создание этого поля или где **Django** его создает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переведите вопрос и ответ на русский язык

Comment: перевел на русский, я не знал, что они разделены)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался сам. Если **Django** не находит **onetoone**-поле к User с параметром `parent_link=True`, то он решает создать свое поле. Потом я увидел, что, хоть в поле и проставлен `parent_link=True`, в миграции его нет, видимо кто-то проставил тут и забыл пересоздать миграции.

Проставил для миграции это поле и всё, **Django** перестал создавать свое поле.